# Formatting data for highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm trying to make charts with Highcharts, but can't figure out why my data isn't in the right format.

When I use the following array as data my chart does his job.

```
fake = [['Joe', 0.1576]];
```

But when I try to make one by pushing elements like this it won't make a chart out of it.

```
name = 'Joe';
percentage = 0.1576;
element = [];
element.push(name, percentage);
graph.push(element);
```

When I compare them by getting them in console they seem totaly the same. But where is the difference between them that is causing the problem?

Edit:

Thanks to your help I found where it should go wrong, probably in the $.getJSON and var 'graph' that is not set properly?

```
    graph = [];
$.getJSON("graph.php",function(data){
    /* Loop through array */
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        graph.push([data[i][1], Number(data[i][3])]);
     }
});

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Individuele productprijzen uiteengezet tegen de totaalprijs'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.2f} %'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: graph
        }]
    });
});
```

The data it gets is in JSON format made with json_encode in PHP.

Comment: Assuming you init graph as `graph = []`, then these are equivalent.  Your problem lies elsewhere.  Also you could shorten it as `graph.push([name, percentage])`

Comment: Shortened it, thanks, but doesn't solve the problem tho.

Comment: What's the rest of the code?  Where/how is graph initiated, or how is it being supplied to the chart?

Comment: I added the code, I think something is going wrong with graph.push but can't figure out what exactly because in console.log() they were both the same.

Comment: Will be better, if you will initialize chart in getJSON response to avoid situation when data is not received.